# How to check whether the script is nulled or not?

Tags: php

How to check whether the script is nulled or not?

Is there any software which detects the php script is nulled or not?

Answer (score 2):

Nulling or checking if a script is nulled needs some experience and checking every file manually, as there are many means of hampering the illegal use of a script.

Automatic methods - if there are any -  will always leave a risk of missing anything. Downloaded "nulled" scripts may also have been compromised and may i.e. open a backdoor on your server. Users of nulled scripts will have some trouble with updates, which they will have to find first and then null or check for correct nulling again, too.

In a nutshell: Nulling is not recommended and usually doesn't pay ...

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check if a script is nulled or not:

1. Prevent every outgoing connection with your firewall.
2. install it on a local machine, maybe you need xampp.
3. Check with your firewall if there are still any connections from the script...

Thats the short description ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is really not possible programmatically, and if yes, it would be really unreliable.

However I've got no idea what would help in detecting whether script is nulled or not

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of your script, you can't tell. The whole point of "nulling" a script is to remove any copyright messages, license checks and related code; any code you added to check for that would simply be stripped out as well.

You can prevent some degree of modification by using a PHP opcode encryptor (e.g, EAccelerator, Zend Encoder, ionCube), at the expense of adding some extra installation requirements and making it much more difficult to debug your application in production.